# Suggestion to improve the script

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below script I am trying to highlight all the words in a sentence

```
function SearchQueue(text)
{  
    if(text !== null)
   {
    text = text.replace(/“/g, "\"");
    text = text.replace(/”/g, "\"");
    text = text.replace(/’/g, "\'");
    text = text.replace(/‘/g, "\'");
    text = text.replace(/–/g, "\-");
    text = text.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');
    $.trim(text);
    text = text.replace(/\d\.\s+|[a-z]\)\s+|•\s+|[A-Z]\.\s+|[IVX]+\.\s+/g, "");
    text = text.replace(/([0-9A-Z]+[.)]|•)\s+/gi, "");
    text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"  ");
   }
   var words = text.split(' ');
   for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++)
       $('*').highlight(''+words[i]+''); // Will highlight the script with background color
 }
```

But this is making my page "unresponsive". Please suggest me to improve the script...

Comment: How many words are there? Also, the empty strings aren't necessary.

Comment: What is the point of `/ +(?= )/`? One or more spaces followed by a space? You could simplify this with just `/ +/` and replace with a single space instead.

Comment: This won't improve the speed, but wouldn't it be a good idea to move your text.split and for statement inside of your null check?  Or better yet replace your null check with if(text == null) return;

Comment: Don't use a plugin to highlight. I take it it searches every single word, every single time? That's not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting the entire dom tree in each iteration which may explain the unresponsiveness.
Try the following:

```
var body = $('body'); // since thats where all the text should live
for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++){
    body.highlight(''+words[i]+''); // Will highlight the script with background color
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine a few of your replaces using a match evaluator (don't know what javascript calls them).

example : http://jsfiddle.net/zyqVE/

```
function match_eval(m){
    switch (m){
        case "“":case "”":
            return "\"";
        case "‘":case "’":
            return "'";
        // etc...

    }  
    return m;
}


alert("this “i“ a test".replace(/[““’‘–]/g, match_eval));
```

in context :

```
function match_eval(m){
    switch (m){
        case "“":case "”":
            return "\"";
        case "‘":case "’":
            return "'";
        case "–"
            return "-";

    }  
    return m;
}

function SearchQueue(text)
{  
    if(text !== null)
   {
    text = text.replace(/[“”’‘–]/g, match_eval);
    text = text.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');
    $.trim(text);
    text = text.replace(/\d\.\s+|[a-z]\)\s+|•\s+|[A-Z]\.\s+|[IVX]+\.\s+/g, "");
    text = text.replace(/([0-9A-Z]+[.)]|•)\s+/gi, "");
    text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"  ");
   }
   var words = text.split(' ');
   for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++)
       $('*').highlight(''+words[i]+''); // Will highlight the script with background color
 }
```

Comment: Looks very intersting.. Could you please implement it in the current function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my first set of adjustments:

```
var $all = $('*');

function SearchQueue(text) {  
   if(text) {
       text = text.replace(/[“”]/g, '"');
       text = text.replace(/[’‘]/g, "'");
       text = text.replace(/–/g, '-');
       text = text.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
       $.trim(text);
       text = text.replace(/\d\.\s+|[a-z]\)\s+|•\s+|[A-Z]\.\s+|[IVX]+\.\s+/g, '');
       text = text.replace(/([0-9A-Za-z]+[.)]|•)\s+/g, '');
       var words = text.split(' ');
       for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
           $all.highlight(words[i]); // Will highlight the script with background color
       }
   }
}
```